# Rational dynamical system with nonnegative paramaters

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, na.numerical-analysis, rational-functions, difference-equations

let $A$ be a rational system of the form :$\begin{cases} x_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_{1}}{y_{n}} \\  y_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_{2}}{z_{n}} \\ z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_{3+}+\beta_{3}x_{n}+\sigma_{3}y_{n}+\lambda_{3}z_{n}}{A_{3}+B_{3}x_{n}+c_{3}y_{n}+D_{3}z_{n}}{}\end{cases}$
$n=0,1,....$

with nonnegative paramaters and with nonnegative initial conditions such that the denominators are always positive.

how i could show that :for every positive solution of the difference equation:
$z_{n+1}= \frac{\alpha}{1+\prod_{i=0}^{k}z_{n-i}},n=0,1,.... $ has a finit limit ?

I pasted this question in stackexchange but i'm not receive any comments or any replies

REF:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1047052/156150

Thank you for any replies or any help.

Comment: Three comments: 1) You should wait a bit longer before cross-posting; 2) Why do you expect that this has a positive limit? 3) What is the relationship between the second difference equation and the first?

Comment: just to define $z_{n+1}$ and the sysetm that i wrote in 3 dimension .